# Flink batch continuous running

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have flink batch job. What is the best way to run continuously? (It needs to restart when it's finished because the streaming job can provide new data)

I want to restart the job immediately if it's finished.

- Infinite cycle and inside call the tasks?
- Make a bash script and always push the job into the jobmanager? (I think it's a really big resource waste)

Thanks

Comment: Why no using a streaming job in the first place?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax how do you think? I want to read the new records from mongodb... What will trigger the stream? Stream is designed (and optimnized) for continuous input processing not for batch job (batch jobs optimized in different ways)

Comment: I quote from your question: "It needs to restart when it's finished because the streaming job can provide new data". Maybe you can elaborate on you overall setting a little bit more. Do you want to process all data from MongoDB in each batch job? Or do you process a "diff"?

Comment: I have a collection, a streaming job write new data when it's come from kafka. The aggregator fetch all data from the collection, filter ( check if their dependencies already exists), process and delete the processed data (there are some data still remain in the collection, and can be processed in the next iteration)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax The main problem with streaming from mongo: You can't detect when the document processed, if the processing needs a long time you can already fetch from the collection.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar use-case where we run Flink job against same collection; we trigger new job at periodic intervals. [daily, hourly etc.] https://azkaban.github.io/ can be used for scheduling. This is NOT really what you mentioned. But, a close-match which might be sufficient to solve your use-case.